# How can I count the numbers greater than 18 in same cell in excel

Tags: excel

How can I count the numbers greater than 18 in same cell in excel

20
26
37;28
17
Not provided
Not provided
Not provided
17
30;26;6;4;3
Not provided
Not provided
30

Comment: I think you need to clarify your post. How may these numbers be separated within the string, for example? Judging by your one example (perhaps a few more would help, by the way), I would suggest that the answer to this question would be: "Either by a semi-colon or by a single space", though this would need confirming by you, of course. And what constitutes a "number" here? For example, in the string "I sold 19 units on the 20th of May", would BOTH the 19 AND the 20 be considered? Or just the 19?

Comment: I mean like this

14 first cell
15 second 
16,14,1,3 third 
18 fourth cell
1,64,48 fifth cell

Comment: yes..................

Comment: I mean like this 
14 first cell 
15 second 16,14,1,3 third 18 fourth cell 1,64,48 fifth cell

Comment: So no semi-colons in the strings now? And numbers are always separated by commas? And what would be your expected result for that range?

Comment: the result should be 7 < 18 and 3 >=18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that:

1) The range in question is A1:A5

2) For a given cell within that range, if there are multiple numbers within that cell then these numbers are only ever separated by commas

then, **array formula****:

`=COUNT(1/(1/(1/(0+(0&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A5,",",REPT(" ",MAX(LEN(A1:A5)))),MAX(LEN(A1:A5))*(COLUMN(INDEX(1:1,1):INDEX(1:1,1+MAX(LEN(A1:A5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A5,",","")))))-1)+1,MAX(LEN(A1:A5)))))))<18))`

Change the <18 at the end as required.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Answer (score 0):

You want to do some pre-processing of the data. From my experience it's easiest to copy the relevant data to notepad (or better: notepad++), and use find and replace (ctrl+h) to replace all separators (commas, semicolons, etc.) by tabs (just copy-paste a tab into the replace by field) and then copy it back to excel. Each data element should now be in its own cell.

Then in excel, use `=COUNTIF(your_range_here,">18")` and it should give you the count of everything greater than 18 (not equal to 18)